# On differential equation $Z'=Z^2-Z$ on a $C^*$ algebra

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, noncommutative-geometry

Let  $A$ be  a Banach or a $C^*$  algebra.  We  consider the  differential  equation $$(*)\;\;\;\;Z'=Z^2-Z$$ on $A$.

> Obviously the  singularities of this systems are just the  idempotents of the  algebra.

It can be easily shown that the group of  invertible  elements is invariant under  this  flow. (**Edit:According to the answer of Robert Israel we get that the space of Left zero divisors  is flow invariant too**.) Furthermore the  group of invertible elements does not contain any periodic orbit(Except the  trivial case of  singularity $Z_0=1$ but  strictly  speaking a singular point can not be  regarded as a periodic orbit). 
Furthermore non of the following algebras can have a  periodic orbit of the  above  systems:

1) The  Matrix  algebra

2)$C^*_{\text{red}} F_1=C^*_{\text{red}} \mathbb{Z}=C(S^1)$

Our  questions:

1)Is there  a Banach or  $C^*$ algebra $A$ for  which the  system $(*)$ has a  periodic orbit?

> 2)In the  literature, are there some researches devoted to Kaplansky or  Kadison Kaplansky  conjecture   via  dynamical  consideration of  the  equation $(*)$? As we see in this post, the three key elements of the Kaplansky  conjecture is meaningfully involved with the dynamical interpretation of $Z'=Z^2 -Z$.These $3$ concepts are "Invertibles", "zero divisors" and "idempotent".

**Proof of the fact that the group of invertible elements of a $C^*$ algebra $A$ is invariant under flow of $(*)$:**

The group of invertible elements of $A$ is denoted by $G(A)$.Let $Z(t)$ be a solution of $(*)$ with $Z(0)=Z_0\in G(A)$. For some $t_0>0$, let $Z(t)\in G(A),\; \forall t\in [0,t_0)$ but $Z(t_0)$ is non invertible. Note that $W(t)=Z(t)^{-1}$ is a solution of $$(**)\;\; W'=W-I$$
Obviousely this vector field $(**)$ is a complet vector field, i.e. all soltions has maximal interval of definitions equal to $(-\infty, +\infty)$. In particular $W(t)$ is defined at $t_0$ hence $W(t)$ is bounded around $t_0$. This situation contradicts to the following lemma which is proved in Functional Analysis by W. Rudin.(10.17 lemma page 256).

**Lemma:** Let $Z_n$ be a sequence of invertible elements of a Banach algebra which converges to a non invertible element then the sequence $W_n=Z_n^{-1}$ is an unbounded sequence.

**Remark:** Please see the comment conversations to the following link as some suggestions for consideration of dynamical methods in the idempotent problem.

[Smooth derivations of a Banach space](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/347732/smooth-derivations-of-a-banach-space)

Answer (score 9):

The solution $Z(t)$ of your differential equation with $Z(0) = Z_0$ satisfies
$$ Z(t) (e^t + (1-e^t) Z_0) = Z_0 $$
In order for this to be periodic with period $p$, you'd need 
$(1-e^p) Z_0 (1-Z_0) = 0 $.  $1-e^p = 0$ (for real $p$) only if $p=0$, while if $Z_0 (1-Z_0) = 0$ we have a fixed point.

Comment: Thank you  very much for  your  answer!  Am  I  mistaken to think that the  formulation of  solution you  wrote is in conflict with the fact that the  group of invariant elements is flow invariant? Let $Z_0$ be  invertible  but  has a real spectrum as $\frac{-e^t}{1-e^t}$.

Comment: The problem is that the solution may not exist globally.  Thus for the equation on the real numbers with $Z(0) = 2$, the solution is $Z(t) = 2/(2 - e^t)$ which blows up at $t = \log(2)$.

Comment: So your statement "the group of invertible elements is flow invariant" really means: if $Z_0$ is invertible and there is a solution $Z(t)$ on an interval $(a,b)$ containing $0$ with $Z(0)=Z_0$, then $Z(t)$ is invertible for all $t \in (a,b)$.

Comment: If $Z_0$ is invertible but $e^t + (1-e^t) Z_0$ is not invertible, it tells you that $Z(t)$ does not exist.

Comment: Is the formula you provided valid in the case that the group of invertible elements is not dense on our algebra? Does you formula give an alternative proof of invariance of invertible elements under flow?

Comment: The formula does not depend on anything being invertible.  It just comes from differentiating $Q(t) = Z(t)(e^t +(1-e^t) Z_0) - Z_0$, substituting $Z'(t)$ from the differential equation, and noting that the result is $Z(t) Q(t)$.  Since $Q(0)=0$ and the local uniqueness theorem applies to the differential equation $Q'(t) = Z(t) Q(t)$, we get $Q(t) = 0$.

Comment: Together with the similar formula $(e^t + (1-e^t) Z_0) Z(t) = Z_0$, it does prove that the set of invertible elements is invariant under the flow.

Comment: Very beautifull argument.!Now I understand your firmula. Just another question: In the mateix algebra do you think that rank is fixed along trajectories. Or in case of operator algebra, Do you think that "trace class operatir or Hilbert Schmidt operatores are flow invariant?

Comment: In the case of matrix algebra, $Z(t)$ has the same generalized eigenspaces as $Z_0$, with eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $Z_0$ becoming $\lambda/(e^t + (1-e^t)\lambda)$ for $Z(t)$ (the solution ceases to exist when the denominator becomes $0$).  So yes, the rank is fixed along trajectories.

Comment: So every orbit is a commutative set.