# Smooth derivations of a Banach space

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, banach-spaces, infinite-dimensional-manifolds, banach-manifold

Let $E$ be a real (or complex) Banach space. By $C^\infty(E) $ we mean the space of all functions $f:E\to \mathbb{R}(f:E\to \mathbb{C})$ which are smooth in the sense of Frechet diffetentiability. A  derivation is a linear map $D:C^\infty (E)\to C^\infty(E)$ which satisfies $D(fg)=D(f)g+fD(g)$.
As an example of a derivation we assume that $H:E\to E$ is a smooth map then we consider   vector field $Z'=H(z)$ on $E$. So we have a derivation $D$ with $D(f)(x)=df(x).H(x)$ where $df$ is the Frechet differential of $f$.

Is there a Banach space $E$ with a derivation $D$ which does not arrive from a vector field as in the above example?

Comment: Any linear form $\phi$ on $E^*$ produces a derivation via $D(f)(x):=\langle \phi, df(x)\rangle$ in your sense, and it arrives from a vector field iff it is an evaluation on a constant vector.  So, if you allow non-continuous $\phi$, any infinite dimensional Banach space has one not coming from a vector field; if you want it continuous, any non-reflexive Banach has it.

Comment: @PietroMajer  Thanks for your answer. To be honnest the motivation for this post is the following: How can one define the Lie bracket of two vector fields in infinit dimensional space. I would like to apply it to the following case: We consider the vector field$ X:\; Z'=Z^2-Z$ on a $C^*$ algebra $A$ then we try to find a vector field $Y:\; Z'=g(Z)$ with $[X,Y]=0$  then idempotents of $A$ are invariant under flow of $Y$.

Comment: The most natural way I think is to define $[X,Y]$ as the Lie derivative $L_XY$  (and the Lie derivative can be defined via the flow of $X$).

Comment: @PietroMajer You mean $L_X Y  -L_Y X$?

Comment: @PietroMajer  my apology for this second message. May you read my previous comment?